# RESTful servlet URLs - servlet-mapping in web.xml

Tags: java, rest, servlets, spring-mvc, url-pattern

I feel like this is a common problem but nothing I've researched has worked yet...

In my web.xml I have a mapping for all REST calls -

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This works well if the URL is -

```
GET /rest/people
```

but **fails** if it is

```
GET /rest/people/1
```

I get a `400 Bad Request` error saying `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()`.  I'm not sure it even made it to the Spring servlet to get routed...

How can I wildcard **anything** that starts with `/rest` so that it can be handled appropriately?

In other words, I'd like for all of the following to be valid -

```
GET /rest/people
GET /rest/people/1
GET /rest/people/1/phones
GET /rest/people/1/phones/23
```

**Edit** - Controller code as requested

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getPeople() {
        return GsonFactory.getInstance().toJson(LookupDao.getInstance().getPeople());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getPerson(@PathVariable String id) {
        return GsonFactory.getInstance().toJson(LookupDao.getInstance().getPerson(id));
    }
}
```

**Answer**

@matsev It didn't seem to matter if I had the `/` there or not.

While I was transposing the variable names for public view I changed a couple things to make it work.

**Original**

```
@RequestMapping(value="{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getPerson(@PathVariable String userId) {
    return GsonFactory.getInstance().toJson(LookupDao.getInstance().getPerson(userId));
}
```

**What I posted**

```
@RequestMapping(value="{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getPerson(@PathVariable String id) {
    return GsonFactory.getInstance().toJson(LookupDao.getInstance().getPerson(id));
}
```

**The variable name mismatch did me in... I leave this here as a warning to all... match your variable names!**

Comment: Can you post your controller code? My guess is that you only have mapped `/people` and not `/people/{id}`.

Comment: @matsev I posted the code for you.  Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: mapping in web.xml is ok. Can you paste here the code of controller class method() for /rest/people/1 ? May be i can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add a `/`before the `{id}`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Without it, the id will be appended directly to the people url, e.g `/rest/people1` as opposed to `/rest/people/1`.